# Bash script running ADB commands won't iterate through list of devices

Tags: android, bash, shell, adb

I have a simple bash script that iterates through a list of devices and runs adb shell commands to Android devices. The code is below:

```
echo "Displaying devices to be configured:"
adb devices | sed "1d ; $ d"
echo ""
echo "###########################"
echo "#                         #"
echo "# Starting configuration! #"
echo "#                         #" 
echo "###########################"
echo ""

while read -r udid device usb product model device2; do

echo ""
echo $usb
echo ""

# INSTALL THE APPS
adb -s "$usb" install ./src/apps/1.apk
adb -s "$usb" install ./src/apps/quicksupport.apk

# SET WIFI OFF
adb -s "$usb" shell settings put global wifi_on 0

# SET SOUND TO 0
adb -s "$usb" shell service call audio 7 i32 3 i32 0 i32 1

# SET AUTO TIME ZONE OFF
adb -s "$usb" shell settings put global auto_time_zone 0

# SET INSTALL NON MARKET APPS ON
adb -s "$usb" shell settings put global install_non_market_apps 1

# REBOOT
adb -s "$usb" reboot

done < <(adb devices -l | sed "1d; $ d")

echo ""
echo "###########################"
echo "#                         #"
echo "# Configuration complete! #"
echo "#                         #" 
echo "###########################"
echo ""
```

When ran, the code will successfully run all configurations on one device. When plugged into two devices, the output reads as follows:

```
Displaying devices to be configured:
0123456789ABCDEF    device
0123456789ABCDEF    device

###########################
#                         #
# Starting configuration! #
#                         #
###########################


usb:336592896X

[100%] /data/local/tmp/1.apk
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/1.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
[100%] /data/local/tmp/quicksupport.apk
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/quicksupport.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
0123456789ABCDEF       device usb:337641472X product:msm8960 model:msm8960 device:msm8960
Result: Parcel(00000000    '....')

###########################
#                         #
# Configuration complete! #
#                         #
###########################
```

It seems to return the remainder of the `adb devices -l` command and than  break out of the loop. Is this an issue with bash? Is this an issue with adb? I've been trying to figure this out for days.

Note: The `Result: Parcel(00000000    '....')` output occurs directly after the sound is set to zero.

Note: Don't mind the `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]`, that occurs because the apps are already installed. That's not what I'm concerned about.

Note: Posting `adb devices -l | hexdump -C`

```
00000000  4c 69 73 74 20 6f 66 20  64 65 76 69 63 65 73 20  |List of devices |
00000010  61 74 74 61 63 68 65 64  0a 30 31 32 33 34 35 36  |attached.0123456|
00000020  37 38 39 41 42 43 44 45  46 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |789ABCDEF       |
00000030  64 65 76 69 63 65 20 75  73 62 3a 34 33 37 33 38  |device usb:43738|
00000040  37 32 36 34 58 20 70 72  6f 64 75 63 74 3a 6d 73  |7264X product:ms|
00000050  6d 38 39 36 30 20 6d 6f  64 65 6c 3a 6d 73 6d 38  |m8960 model:msm8|
00000060  39 36 30 20 64 65 76 69  63 65 3a 6d 73 6d 38 39  |960 device:msm89|
00000070  36 30 0a 30 31 32 33 34  35 36 37 38 39 41 42 43  |60.0123456789ABC|
00000080  44 45 46 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 64 65 76 69 63 65  |DEF       device|
00000090  20 75 73 62 3a 33 33 36  35 39 32 38 39 36 58 20  | usb:336592896X |
000000a0  70 72 6f 64 75 63 74 3a  6d 73 6d 38 39 36 30 20  |product:msm8960 |
000000b0  6d 6f 64 65 6c 3a 6d 73  6d 38 39 36 30 20 64 65  |model:msm8960 de|
000000c0  76 69 63 65 3a 6d 73 6d  38 39 36 30 0a 0a        |vice:msm8960..|
000000ce
```

Comment: They're in there. `echo $usb` returns `usb:336592896X`, the name of the usb I am using to successfully connect to the device. Notice it does not list the `$usb` variable for the second device.

Comment: post `adb devices -l | hexdump -C`

Comment: @AlexP. posted for you.

Comment: try enumerating with `for usb in $(adb devices -l | awk '/ device usb:/{print $3}'); do echo $usb; done` instead

Comment: Would I be replacing the `while read -r udid device usb product model device2; do` with that and deleting the `done < <(adb devices -l | sed "1d; $ d")`?

Comment: yes. replace `echo $usb` with your commands

Comment: It worked! Brilliant! Wold you like to post that as an explained answer so we can give you some credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slightly more efficient and less error prone way of doing the same thing:

```
DeviceConfig () {

# INSTALL THE APPS
adb -s $1 install ./src/apps/1.apk
adb -s $1 install ./src/apps/quicksupport.apk

# SET WIFI OFF
adb -s $1 shell settings put global wifi_on 0

...

adb -s $1 reboot

}

for usb in $(adb devices -l | awk '/ device usb:/{print $3}'); do DeviceConfig $usb; done
```